# Centos - server iso

Tags: centos, centos6

I have downloaded the centos (6) minimal version and am trying to install on a virtual box.

When i fire up the installation, it starts a gui insaller.  I am trying to have a server only iso and this doesnt appear to be it.

Where can I find an ISO that does not have the gui included?

Comment: I remember there was the option to run a text install booting the DVD with `linux text`

Answer (score 5):

The installer having a GUI has no influence on the package selection for installation.
Select 'Minimal' during installation to get a minimal installation suitable for a server.

If you want a completely automated installation without any GUI, have a look at [Kickstart](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can decide if thats a server iso or not, based on the style of the installer. If the download link told you this is a server iso, i would assume it is, unless there is a good reason to think it isn't.

Comment: When i say server i essentially mean no gui.  Apologies.  So i guessed the minimal iso whould not have a gui alas it does appear to

Comment: Just because the installer has a GUI interface, this doesn't mean it will install a GUI or X server when you install the OS. The GUI is only loaded from the iso, without being installed, unless you select the X server to be installed

Answer (score 0):

CentOS minimal version, No GUI in this it is CLI.

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/